# How to get FCM Push notification data received when app backgrounded, but clicked when foregrounded

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've done handling both cases in the docs, which are:

1/ Handle `onMessageReceived` if the app is in the foreground

2/ Handle the payload extras on launcher activity if the push notification is fired when the app is in the background or killed.

But I've run into a case when the push notification is received when the app is in the background (and I just leave them there), then I open the app and use the app as normal. Then I swipe the notification tray down, and I click on the awaiting notification, the app then just got resumed and I have no idea where the payload would go in this case.

I also checked if the payload extras is passed into the current Activity `onResume` with `getIntent().getExtras()` (just like what it does with the launcher Activity) but it doesn't have the extras payload from the notification. Note that the launcher Activity (which is a SplashScreen for my case) is long gone. The app just resume the current Activity.

Is there anyway I can handle this type of click? Or this is a dead end?

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Change or add launchmode of your activity to **singleTop**.That can be done in the AndroidManifest.xml by adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the `<activity>` element.

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. I don't know if FCM behavior allows the extras to... "jump" to current Activity if the app is resumed, not just start a new launcher Activity.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my activity is currently `android:launchMode="singleTop"` now, tried with others as well but none work.